# Conditional filter in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

In my stock, I have a column for showing location of items:

[image]

I want to show specific floor instead of all during print out including blank/a b c d row with single click.

Whenever I select **All**  in B1, it should be show all items. When select 2nd, it should show only 2nd floor items.

Now I want do everything only using B1 dropdown instead of selecting them from E6 filter.

Comment: Can you tell us what you've already tried? SuperUser is a place where we try to help those who themselves have tried to resolve something, but get stuck or run into a problem. You improve your chances of getting a response if you provide details of what you've already tried. This does two things; 1) lets us know you are willing to put in an effort and not expect someone else to just do it for you, and 2) helps us to not suggest what you've already tried

Comment: Thanks that you've inserted my image here. 
Right now i am selecting a floor from B1 dropdown, Later unchecking 2/3 item from location filter. I have to work twice to print every individual floor. I don't know is it possible using VBA or not. Please help me as i m not familiar with those script.

Comment: Try recording a macro of you doing this using the filter in E6. Then try modifying the macro to use B1. THEN post here with specific issues you are facing.